# Per subdirectory and/or file compiler args in meson for c

Tags: c, build, embedded, meson-build

**CONTEXT** 
I have an embedded project that includes different target platforms (eg. ARM using `Arm GNU Toolchain`, Microchip using `MPLAB XC32`, Windows using `MSVC`). Each has it's own "port" subdirectory containing the platform-dependant code. Additionally I have different third-party source files (eg. SDK with auto-generated code, CANOpen stack with auto-generated code, ...).

**PROBLEM** 
I need to compile specific subdirectories with different compiler args for example:

- warnings 
  *unreadable output due to third-party sources and unable to use `werror`*
- optimization levels 
  *optimize already tested or not interested modules on debugging/inspection, due to size constraints (currently done using gcc attributes)*
- defines 
  *enabling detailed logging or other debugging options for the inspecting module*

**APPROACHES**

- The solution to think of was to generate the object files in the subdirectories and link everything together in the root build_target. I would probably be able to get this done by manually compiling the subdirectories using `run_command`, `custom_target` or `compiler.run` but that seems to be a lot of work and I would probably need to add all the different options and args manually.
- I also tried using `declare_dependency` but the `compiler_args` are basically just inherited by the `build_target`.
- My third idea is using `static_library` with `b_lundef=true` (or `/FORCE:UNRESOLVED` respectively), but I am not entirely sure how to set that up to not break debugging or memory sections (eg. initcalls, parameterizable constants, ...).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: With respect to your third-party code, preferably hoist this into a subproject; you can configure warnings on a per-project basis which will allow you to more easily suppress these problems.